# Numpy array to dataframe If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hello trying to create a dataframe but I am getting this if scalar values must pass an index and I am not quite sure how to do that. I've tried a couple methods such as passing an index the length of the Y_test but it did not work.  Thanks

```
type(Y_test) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
type(y_predict) =numpy.ndarray
type(residuals) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

dict3 = {'Test Values':Y_test,'Predictions':y_predict,'Error':residuals}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(dict3)
```

Comment: What are the sizes of `Y_test`, `y_predict` and `residuals`?

Comment: @AbbeGijly everything is the same size 127

Comment: Use the DataFrame column names when creating `dict3`, for example `dict3 = {'Test values': Y_test.Test, 'Predictions' : y_predict, 'Error': residuals.Error}`  (I made up these column names since I can't see yours)